# how to get NSWindow size from kCGWindowNumber?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

```
- (void) GetClientRect 

    NSArray *screenArray = [NSScreen screens];
    NSScreen *mainScreen = [NSScreen mainScreen];
    unsigned screenCount = [screenArray count];
    unsigned index  = 0;

    for (index; index < screenCount; index++)
    {
        NSScreen *screen = [screenArray objectAtIndex: index];
        NSRect screenRect = [screen visibleFrame];
        NSString *mString = ((mainScreen == screen) ? @"Main" : @"not-main");

        NSLog(@"Screen #%d (%@) Frame: %@", index, mString, NSStringFromRect(screenRect));
    }
}
```

Above method is use to get frame for mainscreen.
But i want method which return Screen size of NSWindow whose kCGWindowNumber have been passed.
Any idea ?!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you working with a `CGWindowID` (which is what I assume you meant by `kCGWindowNumber`)? That's a very unnatural thing to do in most circumstances.

Anyway, you can call `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(0, theWindowID)` and examine the dictionary in the first element of the returned array. Use the key `kCGWindowBounds` to get a dictionary representation of the bounds rectangle and then `CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation()` to convert that to a `CGRect`.

---

Are you looking for how to convert the `NSWindow` `-frame`, which is in Cocoa's coordinate system, to the Core Graphics coordinate system? The Cocoa coordinate system has its origin at the **bottom**-left of the primary display, with Y increasing in the **up** direction. The Core Graphics coordinate system has its origin at the **top**-left of the primary display, with Y increasing in the **down** direction.

So, the conversion looks like this:

```
NSWindow* window = /* ... comes from wherever ... */;
NSRect frame = window.frame;
frame.origin.y = NSMaxY([NSScreen.screens.firstObject frame]) - NSMaxY(frame);
CGRect cgbounds = NSRectToCGRect(frame);
```

Comment: Hi @Ken the reason I need to get from `NSWindow` to `CGWindowID` is because I am trying to move a newly created window, to another workspace (Firefox creates the new window and gives me the `NSWindow` to it) is it possible to get `kCGWindowNumber` from `NSWindow`? I am using this method to move window to another workspace - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2368945/1828637

Comment: I thought to use [`[NSWindow windowNumber]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSWindow/windowNumber) but the docs warn its not the same number.

Comment: There is no documented way to get a `CGWindowID` from an `NSWindow`. It's not clear that the `-windowNumber` warning is really about `CGWindowID` or some other number used by the window server. Even if it is, it might mean that `-windowNumber` is not *always* equal to the window's `CGWindowID` because it's negative for off-screen windows. In practice, plenty of people have relied on the fact that, for on-screen windows, `-windowNumber` is the same as the `CGWindowID`.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on that assumption, your code can verify it by getting the window info for a window whose `CGWindowID` is the `NSWindow`'s `-windowNumber`, using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`, and then compare all of the properties to the `NSWindow`'s. If that fails to find a window or the properties don't match, you can get the info for all windows using that same function, search for the one whose properties all match, and take the `kCGWindowNumber` from that. This is prone to false positives if there are two identical windows in your target process.

Comment: I've updated my answer with instructions for how to convert from `NSWindow`'s `-frame` to the Core Graphics coordinate system, which will be necessary to compare to the bounds in the window info dictionaries under the `kCGWindowBounds` key.

Comment: I did a test. I listed all the windows and their titles and their id with `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, then I did `windowNumber` on the `NSWindow` firefox gave me. They matched, but I don't know if I can count it, due to that warning on the docs page. Your not on "on screen windows the `windowNumber` is the `CGWindowID` for fact" helps me incredibly! Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way I don't know if you know but I credit you in my addon description page as top of list contributor for my work :D https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ - http://i.imgur.com/2HNOrTt.png :) thanks so much for all your help to me and everyone :)

Comment: That's very gracious of you. You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words =)