# Move a window to another workspace

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics, core-foundation

This is what I am doing progamatically:

User is currently focused in worksapce 2 because from the main workspace they clicked "fullscreen" green button. 10 seconds later, while they user is in workspace 2, programmatically from my app in main workspace this happens:

Main workspace:
1) Open new window
2) Full screen it
3) `activateIgnoringOtherApps` so it brings my app to top

Step 3. This causes animation and change from the Workspace 2 to main workspace.

I was thinking after step 1 i should move the window i am opening (after 10sec countodwn) to "Workspace 2" I was thinking of using this code here: [How can I programatically move one Terminal.app window to another space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308820/how-can-i-programatically-move-one-terminal-app-window-to-another-space) I am hoping this will not make it change workspace.

My goal is to support 10.6+, will the code in linked topic do the trick so that my window is moved to current workspace, and doing `activateIgnoringOtherApps` will not cause scroll all the way to left.

### Demo

To see exactly what I mean by scrolling workspace you can install my firefox addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/

Then please Shift + Click two times my addon button the gets added to toolbar, then make fullscreen any other app other then firefox. As 10 sec countdown is finished you will see the scroll to newly opened window (which is an image editor on a screenshot)

Here is a youtube screencast showing the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihl8PHjO8fI

Comment: Don't understand your question. Read it three times.

Comment: In that youtube screencast you see i click a button for a screenshot to happen in 10 seconds. Then I make a window full screen. It creates workspace 2. Now after that 10sec countdown is up you notice that black white full screen window is brought into focus by scrolling back to workspace 1. I want to that window show up on top of the fullscreen window i have in workspace 2. I didnt record the end where i close that window and now you see main workspace, i should hav Thanks much for letting me know it didnt make sense so i could clarify and thanks for reading 3 times to try to make sense of it.

Comment: So basically i want that window i open on workspace the user is on, so when they close that window theyll still be on the workspace they were on before i opened the window.