# Applescript to place applications on specific desktops

Tags: applescript, desktop, osx-mountain-lion

I've got an applescript, created in Automator, that opens a number of applications and folders that I use as part of a workflow for creating a photo book.  The way my flow works is Photoshop Elements in Desktop 1, four Finder windows on Desktop 2, iPhoto on Desktop 3 and Booksmart on Desktop 4.

My applescript opens each of these just as I'd like, the only problem is it opens everything on the desktop that I'm on at the time.  I then have to go into mission control and move around my windows putting each application onto the desktop I'd like it to be on.  This takes as long as opening the applications one by one on their requisite desktop.

I have tried assigning desktops to the applications, but this doesn't appear to work consistently.

Is there any applescript that I can use that will open an application on a specific desktop?

I'm running OS X 10.8.2.

Many thanks

Comment: Related questions: [2305491](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305491/applescript-opening-an-app-in-space-number-n), [5691362](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691362/open-an-application-in-a-space-using-applescripts), [9775268](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775268/how-to-move-a-window-to-a-certain-desktop-with-applescript), [14060991](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060991/how-can-i-move-a-window-to-a-target-space-with-applescript-in-os-x-10-8)

Comment: Thanks Lauri, those links were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try assigning the application to a desktop?

[image: context menu]

[image: destop options]

This will open the application on the right desktop without the help of a script.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer will, for instance, place *all* Safari windows on the same desktop, all Finder windows on the same desktop, etc. If you want a specific Safari window and a specific Finder window on different desktops, this approach, while often suggested in answer to similar questions, does not work.