# How to move a window to a certain desktop with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I have an application/window on Desktop 1 (OS X Lion) and I'd like to move it to Desktop 3. Any insights on how to do this? Not as big a deal, but if possible I'd like to ensure there are 3 and only 3 Desktops available.

Comment: By "desktop", are you referring to Lion's version of Spaces?

Comment: I too would like to learn how to do this. Specifically, after a reboot, I want to redistribute a single app's windows back to their original (virtual) desktops. I was thinking I could do this by calling `open -a app -F` and then switch desktops and open specific files, which could partially work for saved docs BUT -F doesn't work on Untitled documents. Those always open on whichever desktop you're on when you start the app.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305588/11976) should offer clues on how to do place applications, specifically...

```
tell application "System Events"
    set x to application bindings of spaces preferences of expose preferences
    set x to {|com.apple.textedit|:4} & x  -- Have TextEdit appear in space 4
    set application bindings of spaces preferences of expose preferences to x
end tell
```

I would imagine moving a window is not too different.

Comment: Alas this uses a specific settings that binds applications to spaces. There is no equivalent setting for windows, so AFAIK this technique is not transferable to windows.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is old, but in case anyone still needs this functionality, I thought I'd share my solution.

Because there aren't any real scripting exposures in Mission Control, you'll need to manipulate the cursor and thus will need access to the Objective-C bridge. This requires using the JXA variant of AppleScript, but still allows things to run natively without any plugins.

If you're still interested I've shared the solution on my GitHub repository, [stephan-hates-osascript](https://github.com/stephancasas/stephan-hates-osascript/blob/main/jxa/move-window-to-desktop.jxa.js).

Comment: Upvoted! This looks like the answer to our prayers! Thanks for doing it! I noticed your script only works for the frontmost window. Would you kindly be able to share examples how to make it work for several apps? My goal is to run a script on startup and place "My App A" on Space 1, "My App B" on Space 3, etc etc. Do you think your script would support that?

Comment: @Luiz, instead of using the included function `FrontmostWindow()`, which relies on `FrontmostApp()`, you can write logic to interface with `System Events` and get the windows you want. For example, if I wanted the first window of *Brave Browser* `Application('System Events').applicationProcesses.byName('Brave Browser').windows.at(0);`

Answer (score -3):

Moving a window works while switching to different desktops with a keyboard shortcut.

With the mouse, click and hold the title bar as if you are moving the window around your desktop, then press ctrl+3.  Ctrl+3 has to be mapped to move to desktop 3 in the keyboard shortcuts interface.  Ctrl+Right twice also works.  Then release the mouse button.

Comment: The question is specifically how to do it with applescript